# VPython: Why do scene.camera.pos and scene.camera.axis never change?

Tags: python-3.x, camera, vpython

I was experimenting in VPython with my scene's camera and I discovered that scene.camera.pos is always equal to <0, 0, 1.73205> and scene.camera.axis is always equal to <0, 0, -1.73205>. These values don't change even when the camera auto-adjusts or when I use the scene.camera.follow function. Why is that? Also, I am able to change these values. However, for the scene.camera.pos it seems like going below 1 doesn't change anything from setting it to one. This is really odd and I hope someone can clear it up for me.

Answer (score 0):

This has been addressed in the VPython forum:

https://groups.google.com/g/vpython-users